# Issue on Generating Dynamic Table From Existing Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/cdtrzh29/) and let me know how I can append values from  selected row(s) by checkbox from a table to new dynamic table?

so far I have tried this

```
var td1 = [];
$('#btn').on('click', function () {
    var checkedRows = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').each(function () {
        checkedRows.push(
        $(this).find('td:gt(0)').map(function () {
            return $(this).html();
        }).get());
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < checkedRows.length; i++) {
        td1.push(parseInt(checkedRows[i][1]));
        td1.push(parseInt(checkedRows[i][5]));
        td1.push(parseInt(checkedRows[i][3]));
        td1.push(parseInt(checkedRows[i][4]));
    }
    $('pre.out').text(JSON.stringify(td1));
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedRows.length; i++) {
        //  $('#newTable').append('<tr>');

    }
});
```

But I got lost on dealing with loading from two dimensional array `checkedRows` so I tried to first load each row to `td1`but still confused!

Please be aware that I am not mean to have all cells value in the new table and it must have only values from same heard.
Here is the HTML

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Model 1</td>
            <td>Shop 2</td>
            <td>Shop 3</td>
            <td>Shop 4</td>
            <td>Shop 5</td>
            <td>Shop 6</td>
            <td>Shop 7</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
            <td>Model 1</td>
            <td>20000</td>
            <td>50000</td>
            <td>20000</td>
            <td>88000</td>
            <td>44000</td>
            <td>30000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='checkbox' /></td>
            <td>Model 2</td>
            <td>20000</td>
            <td>50000</td>
            <td>20000</td>
            <td>88000</td>
            <td>44000</td>
            <td>30000</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<input id="btn" type="button" label="button" value="get rows" />

<pre class="out"></pre>


<table border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Shop 2</td>
            <td>Shop 6</td>
            <td>Shop 4</td>
            <td>Shop 5</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="newTable">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to copy or move the rows?

Comment: no I just want to copy from existing table to new one

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cdtrzh29/2/).

Comment: Great! thats is! thanks a lot

Comment: Should I post it as a answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done the harder part, now with all checked row's data in the array, you can use append() and create the tr/td code for it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkedRows.length; i++) {
    $('#newTable').append('<tr>' + 
                          '<td>' + checkedRows[i][1] + '</td>' + 
                          '<td>' + checkedRows[i][5] + '</td>' + 
                          '<td>' + checkedRows[i][3] + '</td>' +  
                          '<td>' + checkedRows[i][4] + '</td>' + 
                          '</tr>');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdtrzh29/2/).

Bonus: If you want to avoid duply, just change this lines:

```
$(':checkbox:checked').closest('tr').not(".copied").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("copied");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdtrzh29/3/). Then you can disabled the ckeckbox or whatever you want to show user he can't copy that row anymore.

Comment: Thanks DontVoteMeDown! but can you please also let me know how I can use the DontVoteMeDown slice() with checkedRow? I tried this `'<td>' + checkedRows[i][2].slice(0, 9); + '</td>' + ` but I am getting error

Comment: @Suffii what you really want to do, limit the string length to 9 chars?